# Is ther any risk adding primitive Int instead of an Int object?

Tags: java, list

Even if I set up a list as Long type, I can still do this without any errors.
Is there any potential problems I should know?

```
long num = 12L;
List<Long> list = new ArrayList<Long>();
list.add(num)
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html - It pretty much starts with exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. The primitive long will automatically be boxed to a Long.

What might cause a problem is the reverse operation:

```
 long foo = list.get(0);
```

This will unbox the Long to a long, and will throw a NullPointerException if null is stored in the list.

Answer (score 4):

There is no problem. There is something called as `Autoboxing` in java.

This [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html) would help you.

According to the JLS -

> As any Java programmer knows, you can’t put an int (or other primitive value) into a collection. Collections can only hold object references, so you have to box primitive values into the appropriate wrapper class (which is Integer in the case of int). When you take the object out of the collection, you get the Integer that you put in; if you need an int, you must unbox the Integer using the intValue method. All of this boxing and unboxing is a pain, and clutters up your code. The autoboxing and unboxing feature automates the process, eliminating the pain and the clutter.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any potential problems I should know?

No, there won't be any problem. Compiler from Java version 1.5+, will perform *auto-boxing* in this case to convert `long` literal to `Long` object.

However, you should be careful while performing *auto-unboxing* (From `Long` to `long`), as unboxing a `null` reference will result in `NPE`.

For example:

```
list.add(null);
long val = list.get(0);  // NPE will be thrown here.
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with this, because (modern versions of) Java can automatically convert between the object and primitive type in situations such as this. It's called auto boxing.